# PLugin activation error.Custom plugin development

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am developing own plugin.But facing a problem is that , i want to include 2 files into my plugin but the plugin is throwing a notification fatal error.

> Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.

```
<?php
 /*
 Plugin Name: The Foody Core
 Plugin URI: ------------------
 Description: ------------------
 Version: 1.0
 Author: muaz
 Author URI: ------------------------
 License: GPL2
*/


// Exit if accessed directly
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) )
    exit;

    $dirname = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);
    define('THE_FOODY_PLUGIN_PATH', $dirname);

include( THE_FOODY_PLUGIN_PATH . 'shortcodes/shortcodes.php' );
include( THE_FOODY_PLUGIN_PATH . 'config-thefoody/includes.php' );
```

Comment: Hi, what fatal error does it throw?

Comment: @niklaz Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.

Comment: yes, but what is a message of an error. Fatal error - is just a type of error that prevents further execution of code, and all errors throw messages.